# How to fire keypress event from parent into iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, event-handling

I want to develop a website to test an other websites script.

In the website (iFrame) that I want to test i have the following event listener:

```
$(document).ready(function(e){

    $(document).keypress(HandleKeyPress);

});
```

Now I want to trigger a keypress event from my testpage (parent) to test the event listener.

I tried this:

```
var _window = $("#test-container")[0].contentWindow;

...
...

var evt = $.Event("keypress");
evt.charCode = char.charCodeAt(0);

$(_window.document).trigger(evt);
```

But nothing happens?!?!

Answer (score 1):

This is how you target a parent document

```
var parentDoc = window.parent.document
```

Once you have access to the parent document object, you may try whatever you want. and the jquery instance could be found as  below

```
var parentDoc = window.parent.$
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Sorry this was a misunderstanding! my problem is not to target the parent document. My problem is the I want to trigger a keypress event from my parent document inside the iframe but the defined event listener does not react.